# Hazelcast Registration objects causing memory leak while using ScheduledExecutor

Tags: java, out-of-memory, hazelcast

We are using Hazelcast (version 3.8.2) ScheduledExecutor to perform tasks in a cluster. We have a memory issue. 
[image: Zabbix memory graph - OLD GC Usage]

Profiling was done, and we realized that the leak is happening in EventServiceSegment for registration maps.
It's all for .partitionLost events. Or, well, majority.

[image: Yourkit memory profiling]

We know about disposing finished future, and here's our code that is performed on each instance periodically.

```
final long futureDisposed = service.getAllScheduledFutures().values().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .filter(future -> future.getStats().getTotalRuns() > 0).peek(IScheduledFuture::dispose).count();

final long futuresLeft = service.getAllScheduledFutures().values().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).count();
```

What we get when logging those values is okay, correct number of tasks is disposed, and correct number of tasks remains scheduled. At the moment of this heap dump, futuresLeft logged ~2500 scheduled futures as left in the system.
But the memory is still growing.

I've went through code, googled whatever keyword I could find, but nothing helped. I can see that these registrations are supposed to be cleaned when calling dispose, but they are not.

How to properly clean this registrations map when tasks are finished?

Comment: What is the exact Hazelcast version?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's 3.8.2

Comment: According to heap dump analyze, number of `Registration`s, `ScheduledFutureProxy`s and  `ScheduledTaskHandlerImpl`s are ~ same (6.467.036). In the code, there's 1-1 relation between `ScheduledFutureProxy`, `ScheduledTaskHandler` and partition lost listener. So, what do you think as memory leak exactly?

Comment: That they are not getting removed. From what I've read, through code, comments online and documentation, calling dispose should take care of that. At the point of this heap dump, there were ~2500 tasks when calling service.getAllScheduledFutures().

Comment: Ah ok. You mean `ScheduledFuture`s and their outgoing references are leaking, not just partition lost listener registrations. Now that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the lack of information. What I don't understand is why these scheduled futures remain in registration maps?

Comment: I wrote a simple test which schedules tasks in an infinite loop and another thread consumes the futures when they are done and disposes them. But I haven't seen any increasing memory activity. 

Can you provide a code snippet to reproduce the issue, if possible?

Comment: Sure, I'll try to explain it. Our tasks are implemented as HazelcastInstanceAware and Runnable. We have some transient references which we save in HazelcastInstance.userContext.
This is how it's scheduled:

this.scheduler.schedule(createTask(taskId),
    delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

We basically create tasks in hundreds, and schedule them for same delay. After delay, they might get rescheduled (we create a new task object).

I didn't manage to reproduce it locally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152773/discussion-between-mihzr-and-mmdogan).